# Safari PHP session in iframe doesn't work (2019)

Tags: javascript, php, session

I know this question was asked before, but I couldn't find an adequate solution that still works.

I have a little plugin, that consists of an iframe that has another iframe inside it. This structure makes sense since the first iframe only contains some text + button clicking on which opens the second iframe with the actual website (couple interconnected webpages)

It works pretty well on every browser except safari. On safari the actual website doesn't seem to be able to keep the session and on every request/page load it treats you as a completely new visitor.

What makes it weirder is that safari sometimes working just fine. For example I installed this plugin on 3 websites and 1 of them is actually working.

I know that safari just acts weirdly when it comes to session within an iframe, so I really wanted to see if this problem was already solved or is it still a huge issue for people who develop plugins similar to mine

Answer (score 0):

I have the same issue.  The iframe needs to be loaded as the parent page and save a cookie.  Then the iframe will function as expected.  Safari drops all cookies from a different domain in an iframe.

You can test this... clear your history and try a webpage that has the iframe (different domains for parent and iframe)... then load the iframe directly as a the parent page and use it... then go back to the original site and the iframe will work as expected.

I have found other applications that generate an iframe by JavaScript and the iframe keeps the data stored somehow with cookies.